# Relacionamento distante com Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relacionamento

Galera, preciso de uma ajuda urgente!

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Tabelas:

```
saidas
   id
   ...

saidas_produto
   id_saida
   id_entrada_produto

entradas_produtos
   id
   id_entrada
   id_produto
   ...

entradas
  id
  ...
```

Meu sistema de Almoxarifado, trabalha com entrada e saída de vários produtos. Onde uma saída é feita em um item que foi adicionado na entrada (entrada_produtos) -> aqui é onde os itens(produtos) da entrada ficam armazenados. Ou seja uma saída não é relacionada direto com produto e sim com um produto que foi dado entrada.

Consegui fazer o relacionamento certinho em relação a entrada:

```
public function produtos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Estoque\Produto', 'entradas_produtos', 'id_entrada', 'id_produto')->withPivot('id', 'numero_lote', 'vencimento_lote', 'quantidade', 'valor_unitario')->orderBy('entradas_produtos.id', 'asc');
}
```

Como faço para fazer esse relacionamento, passando pela tabela saidas_produtos, pegando meu produto que está dentro de entradas_produtos e pegando o nome do produto que está dentro de produtos?

Já tentei de tudo e nada :(

Comment: @JuniorNunes ai é que ta: se na minha tabela saida_produtos tivesse relação direta com produtos, igual a entrada tem daria pra fazer isso de boa. Mas a saida tem uma particularidade. Note que na tabela saida_produtos eu tenho o id_entrada_produto. Dessa forma, minha forma de da saída não é em um produto direto e sim em um item que foi dado na entrada.

Comment: @JuniorNunes desculpe a ignorância, rsrsrs. Poderia me escrever como está pensando nesse relacionamento?

Comment: A Entrada e a Saída são módulos, digamos que, separados. Um usuário do sistemas primeiro cadastra N produtos, e depois ele vai registrar uma entrada. Uma entrada pode conter N produtos. Feito isso, morreu a entrada. A saída serve para controlar o estoque, no Almoxarifado é feito dessa forma. Onde a saída é feita em um item da entrada (entradas_produtos) > onde aqui está guardado o id do produto. Que serve só como referencia. Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas acredito que eu não preciso obter uma entrada através de uma saída.

Comment: Para as tabelas entradas_produtos e saidas_produtos eu não tenho Model, pra mim são tabelas auxiliares.

Comment: Coloque para mim na sua pergunta o modelo de banco de dados com as relações (diagrama de tabelas e relação)!